# CHtmlView class and focus

Tags: c++, html, mfc, webbrowser-control

I am having Dialog Box Application written in MFC.
Dialog is having 3 child controls on it.
2 Buttons (Button 1 & Button 2) and a HTML Control (Class derived from CHtmlView)
HTML Control has been navigated to a HTML page having 2 checkboxes (Check Box 1 & Check Box 2).

Control Z-Order for focus should be like:
Button 1
Button 2
HTML Control then again Button 1

When focus goes to HTML Control. I want it to set to Check Box 1 & then after pressing tab it will be set to Check Box 2.
But When I press tab while the focus in on Check Box 2, I want it to set to Button 1.

i.e.
I want focus cycle like : Button 1 -> Button 2 -> Check Box 1 in HTML Control -> Check Box 2 in HTML Control -> then again Button 1

Problem:
When the focus is set to HTML Control, it doesn't get set to Check Box 1 and after pressing tab while focus is on Check Box 2 focus doesn't
come back to Button 1.

Let me know if question is not descriptive enough, I will simplify it more.
Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but you may try to add the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT style to the HTML control.

```
int OnInitDialog(...)
{
   HWND html = GetDlgItem(dialog, ID_HTML);
   DWORD ex_style = GetWindowLong(html, GWL_EXSTYLE);
   SetWindowLong(html, GWL_EXSTYLE, ex_tyle | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT);
   return 0;
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But Still the Problem persists.

How can I set focus to Check Box 1 of HTML Control after pressing tab on Button 2 of parent dialog.

Also How can I return focus back to Button 1?

I want focus to cycle as Button 1 -> Button 2 -> Check Box 1 -> Check Box 2 -> Again Button 1.

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Comment: Does the HTML control have the WS_TABSTOP style?

Comment: I have a dialog box with an html control that behaves as expected (at least for the links). The line in the resource file is:

CONTROL "",IDC_EXPLORER,"{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}",WS_TABSTOP,7,210,333,39

Comment: HTML control is having WS_TABSTOP style & I am creating it at runtime through Create call.