# CHtmlEditCtrl::OnSetFocus not being called

Tags: c++, mfc, webbrowser-control

I have derived the CHtmlEditCtrl, and want to be able to react when the control gets or looses its focus. However the standard MFC OnSetFocus and OnKillFocus handling routines are not being  called.

I presume it has something to do with the control actualy being a wrapped ActiveX control.

I have tried giving it the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT and WS_TABSTOP styles on creation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458936/chtmlview-class-and-focus), but it did not help.

I found somewhere that I should make my control the event sink for HTMLDocumentEvents2, but I would rather avoid that if possible.

EDIT: Spy++ says I should be getting WM_PARENTNOTIFY and WM_MOUSEACTIVATE messages. However, my Derived Class receives absolutely no messages. I tried it with OnSize and OnCreate too. No message whatsoever is being sent. Any idea?

Comment: You could try using Spy++ to see what messages you *do* get - might be able to find an alternative - e.g. WM_SETCURSOR.

Comment: Nice idea, Roger. I will try that.

Comment: Usually it's because: Forgot to register to message map, or forgot to declare message map, or forgot to declare/implement dyncreate.